# With AWS I removed elastic IP and can no longer access the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a load balancer and EC2 instance with AWS.  I had problems with e-mail restrictions and was recommended to use an elastic IP.  I then read somethere that you can't use elastic IP and a load balancer so I removed the elastic IP.  I can no longer access my instance even when I've rebooted it and waiting 2 hours later.  I can ping it (after enabling ICMP with network security) but I can't SSH or go to the web server.  All the network settings remain, which included allowing TCP ports for HTTP and SSH.  Does anyone know what has happened to make port 80 and 23 no longer accessible?  This is a real nightmare for me because I did a bit of a marketing campaign, got increased traffic, noticed emails weren't getting sent, then in an attempt to fix that I've screwed the server completely so the website is down at the worst possible time :(

Comment: How are you trying to access the instance exactly? By domain name?

Comment: I've tried the public DNS name and public IP.  I can ping them both now that I enabled ICMP.  But I tried telnetting to them at port 80 and its not connecting

Comment: Are you trying the new public DNS name that was assigned after you removed the EIP?

Comment: Yes.  I'm using the new public DNS name that's now showing up under the "Public DNS" field.  The IP address is now listed as 54.173.242.58 and the public DNS name is listed as ec2-54-173-242-58.compute-1.amazonaws.com in the records for this instance

Comment: Hmm..it seems my question has been marked down.  Can someone offer an explanation?

Comment: Probably because a large proportion of EC2 questions are about network connectivity, and Stack Overflow is supposed to be about programming.  Anyway, ssh is port 22, not 23.  As long as the instance is in the same security group, changing the public IP should not have changed access.  And you can totally use EIPs on instances behind an ELB.

Comment: whoops! Sorry, I meant port 22.  That still remains open from the previous settings.  I'm looking at the system log.  I can see openSSH server and mysql server started.  I don't see any mention of Apache though

Comment: When you try to SSH what message are you getting?

Comment: I get "ssh: connect to host 54.173.242.58 port 22: Resource temporarily unavailable".  Same when using the DNS name

Comment: Did you try reattaching the EIP to this instance and then try to SSH?

Comment: ok, I just reattached the EIP and waited for the new IP and DNS name to be assigned.  The instance records reflect this change.  I've set the security settings to allow all TCP connections and ICMP.  The result is the same however.  I can ping them but cannot connect via port 80 or 22.   I tried telnet, SSH, web browser

Comment: so I decided to ditch that instance and start a new one.  I re-attached the volume from the old instance then start the new instance.  Still can't connect.  All my e-mails finally got sent so the server works. But I noticed this in the system log "AH00557: apache2: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for ip-172-31-49-50

AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it all up.  This isn't a direct solution to the problem, more like a workaround.  I couldn't connect to that server no matter what, so I created a new instance and that worked.  It was as if the Linux server itself was corrupt, not the AWS settings.  I detached the volume from the old instance and attached it as a secondary volume on the new instance.  When I logged into the new instance I was able to mount the secondary volume as a new drive and I just copied the files over that way.  I don't have a bloated server so this wasn't really a big deal to pull off.  Anyway, if you can't log in to a server anymore, you can always mount it to a new instance and access it via the file-system